# How do I change the successHandler of OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using `@EnableOAuth2Sso`. But I need to change the successHandler so that I can change the redirect after login.

How can I do this?

I traced the path of the code:

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso ->
  OAuth2SsoCustomConfiguration ->
   SsoSecurityConfigurer ->
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationConfigurer ->
     OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter ->
      AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter ->
       successHandler
```

Is there anywhere in that path that will allow me to change the `successHandler`?

Maybe it would be possible to access the filters after setup, and modify the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own instance of OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter and add this filter to filter chain.

Given below is the snippet:
`

```
private OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oauth2SsoFilter() {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        OAuth2SsoProperties sso = applicationContext.getBean(OAuth2SsoProperties.class);
        OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = applicationContext.getBean(UserInfoRestTemplateFactory.class)
            .getUserInfoRestTemplate();
        ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices = applicationContext.getBean(ResourceServerTokenServices.class);
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(sso
            .getLoginPath());
        filter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
        filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        filter.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationContext);
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new YourOwnAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        return filter;
    }
```

The filter can be added to filter chain in the following way:

```
http.addFilterBefore(oauth2SsoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
```